# replace all column values not in a list python

Tags: python, replace

I have a df that looks like below:

```
             Animal               Color                Note
         0    Cat                 Brown               Friendly
         1    Dog                 White               Furry
         2    Rabbit              Brown               Furry
```

Now I want the code to check values in all columns and comparing against a list, replace the values that are not in the list with "NA". So the list is

```
  my_list = ['Dog', 'White', 'Friendly']
```

And the desired output is:

```
             Animal               Color                Note
         0    NA                  NA                  Friendly
         1    Dog                 White               NA
         2    NA                  NA                  Furry
```

I found a similar question in below link
[How to replace all values in a Pandas Dataframe not in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866856/how-to-replace-all-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-not-in-a-list)

So as suggested there, I tried the below

```
     df_new = df[~df.isin(my_list)] = "NA"
```

But it gives me "NA" as a result, not the desired df. Could someone please help me with how to fix this? Much appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of your input DataFrame? `df` or `df_in`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
df_new = df.where(df.isin(my_list))
```

output:

```
  Animal  Color      Note
0    NaN    NaN  Friendly
1    Dog  White       NaN
2    NaN    NaN       NaN
```

That said, `df[~df.isin(my_list)] = 'NA'` should also work for **in place modification**, but replace with a 'NA' string, not a real NaN.

**Be careful, `df_new = df[~df_in.isin(my_list)] = "NA"` doesn't make sense as you have a double assignment (and it is unclear what is `df` and what is `df_in`)!**